# Spring Boot Abstract Singleton Service problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi everyone this is my simple project code block

**This service is renewing by sending a request once a day.**

```
 public class SingletonService {

    private static final SingletonService INSTANCE = new SingletonService();

    public static final int TIMEOUT_SEC = 86400 ;//SECONDS every day ONE REQUEST remote service

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    private LocalDateTime queryDate;//Time

    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;//My Remote Employee Repository 

    private  List<Employee> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();


    SingletonService() {//Singleton  Design Pattern
    }

    public static SingletonService getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private boolean isTimeout() {//this methods check date 
        LocalDateTime execDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        if (queryDate == null) {
            return true;
        }
        LocalDateTime expireDate = queryDate.plusSeconds(TIMEOUT_SEC);
        return expireDate.isBefore(execDate);
    }

    public synchronized void reload() {//this methods call repository employee list
        queryDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        list = employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void initQuery() {//this methods check expire date and list size 
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (isTimeout() || list.size() <= 0) {
                reload();
            }
        }
    }

    public Integer countLatestRanking() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void setEmployeeRepository(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public List<Employee> getList() {
        return this.list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Employee> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

My SingletonInitService

```
@Component
public class SingletonInitService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SingletonService.INSTANCE.setEmployeeRepository(employeeRepository);
    }

    public void onContextRefreshedEvent() {
        SingletonService.INSTANCE.initQuery();
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return SingletonService.INSTANCE.getList();
    }
}
```

My EmployeeService

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private SingletonInitService singletonInitService;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        singletonInitService.onContextRefreshedEvent();
        return singletonInitService.getEmployees();
    }

}
```

**My question is how can I write SingletonService abtract because I have too many repositories and I don't want to write this code over and over again (Please don't say why you didn't use the scheduler because it's not good to use job all the time)**

Comment: You’re using Spring so _use Spring_. Why do you have a singleton in the first place? All repositories are singleton scope.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how so?

Comment: How what do? 1) delete your singleton thingy. 2) configure Spring Cache. 3) profit.

Comment: I don't need cache. How can I make this code abstract? It's what I need

Comment: You have an XY problem - you’re not using the tools you’ve been given. I would strongly suggest you read up on my suggestion. Moreover, the code you’ve posted is not correct - for example you lock on `reset` but not on any other method, rendering the lock ineffective.

Comment: Let me tell you something like this, actually there is a remote service with this code. I'm querying it with a Feight client. If there is a difference between the list I received and the list in the repository, then I'm updating my own repository, so it's not the cache, it's something that requires timing for me.

Comment: ok i understand, in my opinion if i don't make singleton then my problem will be fixed thank you